# How do I force RAILS_ENV in a rake task?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake

I have this little rake task:

```
namespace :db do 
  namespace :test do 
    task :reset do 
      ENV['RAILS_ENV'] = "test" 
      Rake::Task['db:drop'].invoke
      Rake::Task['db:create'].invoke
      Rake::Task['db:migrate'].invoke
    end
  end
end
```

Now, when I execute, it will ignore the RAILS_ENV I tried to hard-code. How do I make this task work as expected

Answer (score 53, accepted):

For this particular task, you only need to change the DB connection, so as Adam pointed out, you can do this:

```
namespace :db do 
  namespace :test do 
    task :reset do 
      ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection('test')
      Rake::Task['db:drop'].invoke
      Rake::Task['db:create'].invoke
      Rake::Task['db:migrate'].invoke
      ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(ENV['RAILS_ENV'])  #Make sure you don't have side-effects!
    end
  end
end
```

If your task is more complicated, and you need other aspects of ENV, you are safest spawning a new rake process:

```
namespace :db do 
  namespace :test do 
    task :reset do 
      system("rake db:drop RAILS_ENV=test")
      system("rake db:create RAILS_ENV=test")
      system("rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=test")
    end
  end
end
```

or

```
namespace :db do 
  namespace :test do 
    task :reset do 
      if (ENV['RAILS_ENV'] == "test")
        Rake::Task['db:drop'].invoke
        Rake::Task['db:create'].invoke
        Rake::Task['db:migrate'].invoke
      else
        system("rake db:test:reset RAILS_ENV=test")
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: yes this looks a bit less hacky than mucking around with RAILS_ENV

Comment: For me invoking extra Rake processes looks much *more* hacky.

Comment: It's better than having your task mess with the environment in a destructive way.  If you do it this way you can use it as a dependency in another task without causing a total catastrophe.  Want to run a rake task in test mode?  Run the task in test mode.  Trying to fake test mode, and them probably change it all back to whatever mode you're actually in afterward is sketchy.

Comment: I see your point. I was curious I've just checked how it's done in default Rails db:test tasks and looks like they don't redefine RAILS_ENV but change the database connection manually:
ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(:test)

Comment: I find it interesting, that in order to get this to work properly with a rake db:reset, I HAD to use the "system" version of this answer.  The others all failed miserably, usually wiping out my development database.

Comment: I had to use the system calls too: Which were really really slow.

Answer (score 19):

In Rails 3, you'll have to use

```
Rails.env = "test"
Rake::Task["db:drop"].invoke
```

instead of

```
RAILS_ENV = "test"
Rake::Task["db:drop"].invoke
```

Answer (score 11):

Another option is to check the env and refuse to continue:

```
unless Rails.env.development?
  puts "This task can only be run in development environment"
  exit
end
```

or ask if they really want to continue:

```
unless Rails.env.development?
  puts "You are using #{Rails.env} environment, are you sure? y/n"
  continue = STDIN.gets.chomp
  exit unless continue == 'y'
end
```

Answer (score 7):

The cleanest and simplest solution would be to redefine `RAILS_ENV` (not `ENV['RAILS_ENV']`)

```
namespace :db do
  namespace :test do  
    task :reset do 
      RAILS_ENV = "test" 
      Rake::Task['db:drop'].invoke
      Rake::Task['db:create'].invoke
      Rake::Task['db:migrate'].invoke
    end
  end
end
```

During the boot process of a Rails application RAILS_ENV is initialized as follows

```
RAILS_ENV = (ENV['RAILS_ENV'] || 'development').dup unless defined?(RAILS_ENV)
```

The rest of Rails code uses `RAILS_ENV` directly.

However, as Michael has pointed out in a comment to his answer, switching `RAILS_ENV` on the fly can be risky. Another approach would be to switch the database connection, this solution is in fact used by the default `db:test` tasks

```
ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(:test)
```

Answer (score 4):

The best way of course is to specify the environment from the command line when you run the rake task, but if for some reason that's not what you want to do, you can do this:

```
ENV["RAILS_ENV"] = 'test'
RAILS_ENV.replace('test') if defined?(RAILS_ENV)

load "#{RAILS_ROOT}/config/environment.rb"
```

And that should do the trick.

Comment: You may just be able to `require 'config/environment'` instead of reloading it.

Answer (score 4):

There is some strange code in `database_tasks.rb`:

```
  def each_current_configuration(environment)
    environments = [environment]
    environments << 'test' if environment == 'development'

    configurations = ActiveRecord::Base.configurations.values_at(*environments)
    configurations.compact.each do |configuration|
      yield configuration unless configuration['database'].blank?
    end
  end
```

It always adds `test` if env is `development`.  I solved the case of wanting to do a custom `db:rebuild` task for simultaneous `development` and `test` by running `development` first, and `test` second.  In addition, before running the tasks, I call my `set_env` method which makes sure to set `ActiveRecord::Tasks::DatabaseTasks.env`, without this, the database connections don't seem to be handled discretely for environments as expected.  I tried all other sorts of disconnect etc, but this worked without further code.

```
def set_env(env)
  Rails.env = env.to_s
  ENV['RAILS_ENV'] = env.to_s
  ActiveRecord::Tasks::DatabaseTasks.env = env.to_s
end
```

---

[Here is a gist of my full `db.rake` file with simultaneous multi-environment `db:rebuild` and `db:truncate`](https://gist.github.com/rosskevin/7549349)

Comment: It has been working for us in rails 4 since it was introduced and still works today.

Comment: Thanks. ok, I'm gonna look at your gist now.

Answer (score 0):

Rails itself uses `system` to restart process.

https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/8ec74553851bfafd1cc6944a1baad82c13fa76ff/railties/lib/rails/test_unit/runner.rb#L35

That means there is no way to override `Rails.env` after Rake tasks loaded.

This is my solution:

```
# rubocop:disable Rails/RakeEnvironment
task :force_test_env do
  unless Rails.env.test?
    tasks = Rake.application.top_level_tasks
    exec({'RAILS_ENV' => 'test'}, 'bin/rails', *tasks)
  end
end
task :test_env => [:force_test_env, :environment]

task :your_task_for_test => :test_env do
  YourTask.exec
end
task :your_another_task_for_test => :test_env do
  YourTask.exec :another
end
```

`force_test_env` restarts process. This task doesn't require `environment`.
`test_env` task do the trick.