# How do I override database connection info for a rake task in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake

I have a rails rake task and I want it to ignore what is in database.yml and use something else.  How do I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection` to set up a database connection within a Rake task, as described [in this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1090176/how-do-i-force-rails-env-in-a-rake-task).

Or create a separate environment and add the database configuration to `database.yml`. Then call the rake task with `rake mytask RAILS_ENV=myenvironment`

Answer (score 0):

You can also have direct access to the database inside a rake task by using this format:

```
desc "Some task"
task SomeTask: :environment do
  Author.all.each do |author|
    ... some code
  end
end
```