# environment change in rake task

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I am developing **Rails v2.3** app with **MySQL** database and `mysql2` **gem**. I faced a weird situation which is about **changing the environment** in **rake** task.

(all my setting and configurations for environment and database are correct, no problem for that.)

Here is my simple story :

I have a rake task like following:

```
namespace :db do
   task :do_something => :environment do
       #1. run under 'development' environment
       my_helper.run_under_development_env

       #2. change to 'custom' environment 
       RAILS_ENV='custom'
       
       Rake::Task['db:create']
       Rake::Task['db:migrate']

       #3. change back to 'development' environment
       RAILS_ENV='development'
       
       #4. But it still run in 'customer' environment, why?
       my_helper.run_under_development_env 
   end

end
```

The **rake** task is quite simple, what it does is:

**1.** Firstly, run a method from `my_helper` under "**development**" environment

**2.** Then, change to "**custom**" environment and run `db:create` and `db:migrate`

until now, everything is fine, the environment did change to "**custom**"

**3.** Then, change it back again to "**development**" environment

**4.** run helper method again under "**development**" environment

But, though I have changed the environment back to "**development**" in step 3, the last method still run in "**custom**" environment, why? and how to get rid of it?

**--- P.S. ---**

I have also checked a post [related with environment change here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1090176/how-do-i-force-rails-env-in-a-rake-task), and tried to use the solution there (in step 2):

```
#2. change to 'custom' database
ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection('custom')
Rake::Task['db:create']
Rake::Task['db:migrate']
```

to change the database connection instead of changing environment but, the `db:create` and `db:migrate` will still run under "**development**" database, though the linked post said it should run for "**custom**" database... weird

**--------------- important update ---------------------**

I just realize that the code in step 2:

```
#2. change to 'custom' environment 
RAILS_ENV='custom'

Rake::Task['db:create']
Rake::Task['db:migrate']
```

it changes environment to "**custom**" **only if** the `Rake::Task['db:create']` get called, if I comment out `Rake::Task['db:create']` line, code will still run under '**development**':

```
#2. change to 'custom' environment 
RAILS_ENV='custom'

#Rake::Task['db:create']
#CODE WILL RUN STILL UNDER 'development' environment.
```

Why `Rake::Task['db:create']` affects environment change in my case...?

Answer (score 3):

I realize this question is from over a month ago, but what they heck - it's Christmas

it seems like running each rake task in its own process will simplify things when switching environments?

```
namespace :db do
    task :do_something => :environment do
        unless Rails.env.development? then
           raise "Can only run under development environment, but specified env was #{Rails.env}"
        end 

        #1. run under 'development' environment
        my_helper.run_under_development_env

        #2. do the giggity with custom environment
        command = "bundle exec rake db:create RAILS_ENV=custom"    
        result = %x[#{command}]
        raise "rake task failed..........\n#{result}" if result.include?('rake aborted!')

        command = "bundle exec rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=custom"    
        result = %x[#{command}]
        raise "rake task failed..........\n#{result}" if result.include?('rake aborted!')


        #3. back to development
        my_helper.run_under_development_env 
    end
end
```

Comment: Thumbs up for actually answering on Christmas Day. Either things were pretty slow in your household or you got a new computer from Santa. :)

Answer (score 1):

just type after the rake task RAILS_ENV='production'

in your case

rake db:do_something  RAILS_ENV='custom'