# Only load rake rasks in a certain environment?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake, bundler

Right now, I'm using bundler to manage my gems. Bundler loads different gems for different environments.

I have some rake tasks that use testing gems (rspec), but these cause problems in production environments where that gem isn't loaded.

So what I'd like to be able to do is to only have the rake task (and the require 'rspec/core/rake_task' line associated with it) load in the test environment.

I can't quite figure out the best way to do this.

I currently have:

```
require "bundler"
require 'rspec/core/rake_task'

desc "Task for running Rspec tests"
RSpec::Rake::SpecTask.new(:spec)
```

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1090176/how-do-i-force-rails-env-in-a-rake-task

Answer (score 12):

How about:

```
require "bundler"

unless Rails.env.production?
  require 'rspec/core/rake_task'

  desc "Task for running Rspec tests"
  RSpec::Rake::SpecTask.new(:spec)
end
```

Not the prettiest solution, but it will work.

Comment: Actually, that require there would still cause a failure I think. But I suppose that it could be wrapped in the unless as well.

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution, perhaps not ideal for all setups, is to add the rake task to your gitignore.