# How to drop test and development database in one rake task?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I tried to drop the test and development databases from one rake task like this:

```
task :regenerate do
  Rails.env = "test"
  Rake::Task["db:drop"].invoke
  Rails.env = "development"
  Rake::Task["db:drop"].invoke
end
```

The test database was dropped successfully. But the development database was not dropped.

Any ideas on how to make this work?

NB: This is on Rails 3.2.3

**UPDATE:**

Very odd, but reversing the order works:

```
task :regenerate do
  Rails.env = "development"
  Rake::Task["db:drop"].invoke
  Rails.env = "test"
  Rake::Task["db:drop"].invoke
end
```

What is going on?!

Comment: take a look : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1090176/how-do-i-force-rails-env-in-a-rake-task

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Reversing it does work, because there is some strange code in `database_tasks.rb`:

```
  def each_current_configuration(environment)
    environments = [environment]
    environments << 'test' if environment == 'development'

    configurations = ActiveRecord::Base.configurations.values_at(*environments)
    configurations.compact.each do |configuration|
      yield configuration unless configuration['database'].blank?
    end
  end
```

It always adds `test` if env is `development`.  I solved the case of wanting to do a custom `db:rebuild` task for simultaneous `development` and `test` by running `development` first, and `test` second.  In addition, before running the tasks, I call my `set_env` method which makes sure to set `ActiveRecord::Tasks::DatabaseTasks.env`, without this, the database connections don't seem to be handled discretely for environments as expected.  I tried all other sorts of disconnect etc, but this worked without further code.

```
def set_env(env)
  Rails.env = env.to_s
  ENV['RAILS_ENV'] = env.to_s
  ActiveRecord::Tasks::DatabaseTasks.env = env.to_s
end
```

---

[Here is a gist of my full `db.rake` file with simultaneous multi-environment `db:rebuild` and `db:truncate`](https://gist.github.com/rosskevin/7549349)

Answer (score 5):

You can write it like this:

```
namespace :db do
  desc "Database custom drop"
  task :mydrop do
    system("rake db:drop RAILS_ENV=test")
    system("rake db:drop RAILS_ENV=development")
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

On my system with Ruby 2 and Rails 3.2.13 I can run rake db:drop

This drops both test and development databases. Much easier now than messing with rake tasks