# Ruby on rails specify environment in rake task

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake, seed

I want to create a custom `db/seeds` file and pass it to a specific environment

```
desc "Select for bonus"
task :bonus => :environment do
  puts "Bonus for: #{pick(User).name}"
end
```

Is is possible in the task section of my rake task to specify say only the test environment without having to run `RAILS_ENV=test rake` in my command line?

Comment: You can always change the environment with `ENV['RAILS_ENV']="a value"`, but it sounds like you need RAILS_ENV to be set _before_ ruby executes.

Answer (score 1):

If all you are doing is seeding the database with this specific task, you just need to establish connection with the right database as part of the task.

```
desc "Select for bonus"
task :bonus => :environment do
  puts "Bonus for: #{pick(User).name}"
  ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection('test')
  ....
end
```

`ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection('test')` above connects to the `test` database before running the rest of the steps on that database.

If you are doing lot more complicated things as part of the task, that is possible too. See [How do I force RAILS_ENV in a rake task?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1090176/how-do-i-force-rails-env-in-a-rake-task) for some tips.