# In Rails 4, how can I have a Rake task minify my assets?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rake, asset-pipeline

I need to export a subset of my assets to some external sites. I've created a rake task to do that:

```
rake build:navbar
```

The problem is I cannot get the assets library to minify my library. Here's the code from my task method:

```
desc "Build navbar assets and markup for other sites."
task navbar: :environment do

  # Set environment to production so pipeline will minify assets.
  Rails.env = "production"

  # Some setup code removed...

  # How do we coax assets into minifying files?
  Rails.application.config.assets.prefix = "../build/navbar/staging"
  Rails.application.config.assets.js_compressor = :uglifier
  Rails.application.config.assets.css_compressor = :sass
  Rails.application.config.assets.digest = false
  Rails.application.config.assets.compress = true
  Rails.application.config.assets.debug = false
  Rails.application.config.assets.paths = [Rails.root.join('/app/assets/javascripts'),
                                           Rails.root.join('/app/assets/stylesheets/navbar')]
  Rails.application.config.assets.precompile = ['navbar.js', 'navbar.css']

  # Compile now.
  Rake::Task['assets:clean'].invoke
  Rake::Task['assets:precompile'].invoke

  # Cleanup code removed...
end
```

It will generated a *compressed* version of my assets (`navbar.css.gz`), but not a minified version (`navbar.min.css`).

I've googled this up and down and it seems like this recipe of settings should do the trick. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

I think I've identified the underlying problem. The assets pipeline task, i.e. [sprockets-rails](https://github.com/rails/sprockets-rails), doesn't fully respect config settings. It seems to override some settings depending on the Rails environment. And you can't simply [change the Rails environment within a rake task](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1090176/how-do-i-force-rails-env-in-a-rake-task/1090319#1090319).

The goal, again, is to port a subset of the Rails application's assets for another project using this rake command:

```
rake build:navbar
```

Here's some sample code that shows how I worked around these issues:

```
namespace :build do
  desc "Build navbar assets and markup."
  task navbar: :environment do
    # Prep Builder
    builder = Navbar::Builder.new(target: target)
    builder.prep_build

    # Why this? Setting Rails.env or ENV['RAILS_ENV'] didn't work.
    system("rake build:navbar_assets RAILS_ENV=production")

    builder.generate_markup_file
    builder.move_output_files_to_build_directory
    builder.cleanup
  end

  desc "Build navbar assets."
  task navbar_assets: :environment do
    # Configure the asset pipeline to compile minified files.
    # NOTE: Sprockets only minifies files in production environment (or won't
    # do it in development) so this assumes RAILS_ENV is set to production
    # on the command line.
    Rails.application.config.assets.prefix = "../build/navbar/staging"
    Rails.application.config.assets.paths = [Rails.root.join('app/assets/javascripts'),
                                             Rails.root.join('app/assets/stylesheets')]
    Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += ['navbar.js', 'navbar.css']

    # Let it rip.
    Rake::Task['assets:clobber'].invoke
    Rake::Task['assets:precompile'].invoke
  end
end
```

There were also some issues with file-path-building in the code in the question. Those have been corrected.